# What is the take on getting older (possibly obsolete) languages reviewed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-language

Specifically, I want to address languages from the era of 8-bit home computing. Such languages could include:

- 6502 Assembly
- 6800 Assembly
- 8080 Assembly
- Commodore BASIC
- etc...

These languages are specific to a processor / computer that is obsolete nowadays. There are, however, several simulators and such that can allows you to compile / run these programs. But I don't know the age range of people on this site. I my self am 17 and know them, but most people that didn't use computers at that time would not be familiar with them, and they could be a pain for some reviewers.

Should we allow reviews in these languages?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Of course these languages are allowed.  We have users in our chat room who grew up programming on these systems, and while the [assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly) user base isn't as strong as others, it is large enough that you could likely get a review.

Answer (score 11):

Absolutely! The newest [cobol](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cobol) question was asked [last April](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cobol?sort=newest&pageSize=50), and it's funny you bring up C64 [basic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic) just recently I was considering finding an emulator and [implementing a tic-tac-toe game](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=23584079#23584079) and putting it up for review on the main site.

> *[...] they could be a pain for some reviewers.*

Sure. And they could be a *challenge* for some other adventurous reviewer that's *reviewing code as a sport*. After all, except for [some esoteric languages](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/57382/23788), the structures are pretty much the same, and reviewing the algorithm doesn't require thorough knowledge of a language.. answers don't even need to contain a single code block anyway.

Even when the day comes where [assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly) can't be compiled anywhere anymore, we'll keep these tags around, be it only for their historical value :-)

Comment: It's the year 2052. Somewhere, deep in a forgotten server room, a bug rears its ugly head. The business is in a panic. IT tracks the issue back to an ancient mainframe service written in assembly...